# Paper camera software filters for post-production?

Tags: video, effects, filter

I have downloaded an android app called [Paper Camera](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.dama.papercamera) that provides real time camera filters such as a variety of 'sketch' and cartoony feels. I find especially interesting their filters 'Contour', which is pretty much B&W contour lines, and 'Sketch Up' which looks like a rough pencil drawing.

What kind of software and what filters could I use to apply similar effects to an already recorded video file?

Comment: I'm not sure how that second question is related, other than also being about an Android tablet. If it isn't, it'd fit better as a second question, so that we aren't doubling up on questions and answers.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking about doing just that. Thanks! http://avp.stackexchange.com/questions/2791/screen-record-tablet-ink-drawing-on-top-of-recorded-video

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Adobe Premiere](http://www.adobe.com/products/premiere.html) should do exactly what you want - it has a ton of effects plugins.

As to your second question, any screen grabber video software should let you do this - you play the video and have your wacom sketch overlay running, and just use the screen grabber software to make a video of everything displayed on the screen.

Comment: I made a separate question for the second inquiry.

Comment: Would Adobe Premiere Elements also offer me such plugins?

Comment: I haven't tried Elements, but a quick google comes up with some plugins which appear to do 'sketch' type effects.