# Screen-record tablet ink drawing on top of recorded video?

Tags: editing, screen-casting

Is there software that allows me to 'screen record' tablet wacom ink drawing on top of a video being played back, and then output a new file with the drawing being part of the video?

A wacom overlay, for instance, only sends input commands to what you currently have on screen, it doesn't create 'ink' on the screen (like in say, Windows Journal or Onenote). To make a wacom overlay create ink, you open a drawing program. But then I can't have the video playback on the same screen, so I think I'd need a screen recorder software with actual inking support built-in so it creates the ink on top of video. Is there such a thing?

A use case would be annotating a screencast with inking to point to and mark things up.